# How to work with inheritance in objective-C (iOS sdk)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, model-view-controller

I just started to learn iOS programming and I have a problem with inheritance. There are 2 files.

**First file**

Header

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface ViewController : UIViewController {
    int x;
}
@end
```

Implementation:

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "NewClass.h"
@implementation ViewController
#pragma mark - View lifecycle
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    x = 999;
    NewClass *myClass = [[[NewClass alloc] init] autorelease];
}
@end
```

**Second file**

Header:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface NewClass : ViewController 
@end
```

Implementation:

```
#import "NewClass.h"
@implementation NewClass

-(id)init { 
    self = [super init];                                       
    if (self != nil) {                                            
        NSLog(@"%i",x);
    }
    return self;                           
}
@end
```

In ViewController I set x to 999, and in NewClass I want to get it, but when I call `NSLog(@"%i",x);` it gives me 0.

Where did I make a mistake?

Comment: And when i call NSLog(@"%i",x) in NewClass i want to see 999. How to solve what problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have a timing problem.

1. The `init` method gets called first (at all levels of the inheritance hierarchy, so in both `ViewController` and `NewClass`). This is when you print out your value of `x`, when it is still zero.
2. The `viewDidLoad` method only gets called much later, generally at a point after a view controller's view has been added to a superview. It's functionality that's specific to the `UIViewController` class.

To make your example work, put an `init` method in your `ViewController` class that looks like the one in your `NewClass` class, and set x there.

Also, you don't need to create a `NewClass` instance within `ViewController`. When you create a `NewClass` object, it is automatically a `ViewController` as well. In the same way that a dog is an animal automatically, and so is a cat. When you create a dog, you don't want to create an animal as well!

As sidyll says, you should probably do a bit more reading about how inheritance works, I'm afraid!

Comment: But why i don't need to create NewClass within ViewController , if i don't do what, how i can call init method in NewClass?

Comment: If you do: `[[NewClass alloc] init]`, then it will first call NewClass's init method. This will in turn call ViewController's init method (because you do `[super init]`), before returning to your NewClass to do run your NSLog code. Seriously, read more OOP tutorials!

Answer (score 6):

You need to review you OOP concepts. [Object-Oriented Programming with Objective-C](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/OOP_ObjC/Introduction/Introduction.html) is a must.

Your class `NewClass` indeed inherits the `x` variable, but not it's value. When you create an instance of it, you're creating a shiny new instance whose values have nothing to do with the parent class.

Another point of view to help you is that `x` was set in a object of `ViewController` class. The `NewClass` inherits from `ViewController` **class**, not from an arbitrary instance (object, where you set `x`).

Answer (score 0):

That's because `-viewDidLoad` is not called until well after `-init` returns. Your superclass should do configuration like that in its `-init` method.